# Options for deck-mount, single-handle tub mixer valves

Tags: faucet

I'm installing a tub in a remodel bathroom. *Just* a tub, no shower. I'd like to have a single-handle control, and a hand shower.

Such fixtures are scarce, and most out of my budget. I'm wondering, single-handle mixers are everywhere in walls: everyone has seen one of these:

[image]

Trouble is such a large trim ring on the deck of the tub would be...awkward. However, it's usually possible to purchase just the valve mechanism. Is it generally possible to take the value, but put a more ordinary deck-mount handle on it, for example:

[image]

The answer must be manufacturer dependent, but I can't even find where manufacturers say what knobs are compatible with what valves. Is this a thing people do? Am I searching for the wrong terms?

Answer (score 0):

You can always buy the valve alone.  Why do you not want to mount the valve on the wall? I wouldn't plan the handles being interchangeable.

Comment: I'd rather not have to get out of the tub to walk to the wall to adjust the water.

Answer (score 0):

Is this a free standing tub? If so, you could build a box from the floor or wall then install whatever hardware you want.